# Auto Fill formula down till last row in data set

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am looking to copy multiple formulas in multiple columns down to the end of my dataset. This is what I have thus far and it is working just fine.

```
Sub CopyFormulas()
Dim Lastrow As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Lastrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A3:A" & Lastrow).Formula = "=D3&LEFT(C3,10)"
Range("B3:B" & Lastrow).Formula = "=D3&C3"
End Sub
```

However, I am trying to add in an additional formula to copy down in column I and I am receiving a Syntax error - here is the additional line that is erroring out:

```
Range("I3:I" & Lastrow).Formula = "=IF(E3="-","-",LEFT(E3,FIND("(Primary)",E3)-2))"
```

Can anyone advise what it is about this formula that is causing the error? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to **double the inner quotation marks**:

```
Range("I3:I" & lastrow).Formula = "=IF(E3=""-"",""-"",LEFT(E3,FIND(""(Primary)"",E3)-2))"
```

Side note: if there is no "-" nor "(Primary)" the formula will return an error.

Comment: Very good. As you're new on SO: please don't forget to accept my answer if it helped you to solve your problem. See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)